# Django slowdown - thousands of unused datababase calls

Tags: python, django, performance, apache2, psycopg2

I have a weird issue with a database consisting of about 27,000 items in the main table, and ~400,000 items in a many-to-many linking those items.  The database is a Postgresql, running from Psycopg2, on a Django server that is on Mod_wsgi on Apache2.

This particular view slows down to 10-20 seconds to render.

I am having a hard time finding where this slowdown is coming from.  Simple logging tells me that the view is taking less than 75 ms to actually render, so it's not the view logic or the templates.  And the SQL queries that are being executed for the view take about 35 ms total.  So there are several seconds of operations that I can't see happening.

Profiling tells me this:

```
 ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     5597    3.750    0.001    3.820    0.001 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py:52(execute)
303114/66508    2.518    0.000    5.290    0.000 /usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py:145(deepcopy)
   297634    0.762    0.000    0.762    0.000 /usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py:267(_keep_alive)
    16627    0.622    0.000    6.145    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py:242(clone)
44159/22079    0.449    0.000    2.531    0.000 /usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py:234(_deepcopy_tuple)
     5597    0.423    0.000    4.653    0.001 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py:37(execute)
38706/33254    0.374    0.000    2.970    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/tree.py:55(__deepcopy__)
    10961    0.367    0.000    0.599    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py:326(__init__)
    16558    0.322    0.000    8.946    0.001 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py:241(iterator)
     5597    0.293    0.000    2.071    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:56(as_sql)
     5602    0.266    0.000    0.983    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py:1035(add_filter)
     5597    0.232    0.000    0.540    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:242(get_default_columns)
94039/83135    0.221    0.000    1.783    0.000 /usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py:226(_deepcopy_list)
    44448    0.216    0.000    0.216    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py:121(__init__)
    22209    0.207    0.000    0.207    0.000 /usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py:15(decode)
    22080    0.199    0.000    1.550    0.000 /usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py:306(_reconstruct)
     5723    0.198    0.000   15.201    0.003 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py:367(__get__)
     5597    0.194    0.000    0.323    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py:104(__init__)
    16627    0.179    0.000    6.396    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py:904(_clone)
    66702    0.174    0.000    0.174    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/tree.py:18(__init__)
     5597    0.162    0.000    0.787    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:162(get_columns)
     5597    0.161    0.000    0.302    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py:160(_cursor)
    44448    0.159    0.000    0.159    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py:116(__new__)
    11182    0.149    0.000    0.304    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:854()
    16627    0.145    0.000    0.315    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py:136(__deepcopy__)
    40271    0.140    0.000    0.209    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:40(quote_name_unless_alias)
    16558    0.131    0.000    7.713    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:763(results_iter)
    34669    0.129    0.000    0.129    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/operations.py:71(quote_name)
16796/11194    0.128    0.000    0.689    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py:76(as_sql)
    22224    0.123    0.000    0.446    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py:36(__init__)
        1    0.115    0.115    0.115    0.115 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:119(connect)
     5437    0.112    0.000   14.141    0.003 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py:374(get)
     5598    0.111    0.000    1.232    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py:1235(add_q)
        1    0.109    0.109    0.109    0.109 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loaders/filesystem.py:33(load_template_source)
     5602    0.108    0.000    0.561    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py:148(make_atom)
```

So it looks like there are thousands of calls being done to Base.py,  and deepcopy, but when I look at the connection.queries value for the view, there are only 7 total, and totalling about 35 ms.

Has anyone run into this issue before?  There are no loops in my view code, it's all normal heuristics, pk-based lookup, and saving.

Comment: Post view code please.

Comment: I'm not familiar with profiling enough.. but I've found New Relic's free plan is even enough to break down rendering details into very usable chunks. External network calls, template rendering, SQL (though you see this already)

Comment: Pls post some of your code... And check you SQL queries with a tool like django-debug-toolbar...